# swift 3 - how to swipe remove table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

```
import UIKit

class PartiesTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    let cellIdentifier = "partyCell"
    var parties: [Party]?
    let persistence = Persistence()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short

        print("PartiesTableViewController.viewDidLoad() begins")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        parties = persistence.fetchParties()

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    //UITableViewDataSource
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return parties?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        print("PartiesTableViewController.tableView() begins")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        if let parties = parties
        {
            let party = parties[indexPath.row]

            print("partyname = \(party.name) \(party.startDate)")

            let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: party.startDate)

            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(party.name) - \(strDate)"
        }

        return cell
    }

    //UITableViewDelegate - delete
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete)
        {
            parties.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
    }
}
```

I am very new to iOS development and this is my first todo list project. I was trying to swipe delete table view cell data from the screen. But the way I did seems incorrect way. Can anyone help me to implement deleting cell method please? last line `parties.remove(at: indexPath.row)` gives the error:

> "Value of type '[Party]?' has no member 'remove'

Answer (score 1):

You must unwrap the `parties` optional. You'll also have to reload the table after modifying the parties array.

```
parties?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableView.reloadData()
```

For more info about optionals: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional

Comment: Thank you very much for putting tableView.reloadData().

Comment: but it doesn't delete permanently. When I re-run the app, it restores all data.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
parties.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

to

```
parties?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! but I think it would have been better if you added tableView.reloadData() too.